# QCameraInfo not recognising multiple cameras from frame grabber

Tags: c++, qt, frame-grab, qcamera

I have developed an application to show the camera output. Cameras are connected using the frame grabber card (PCIe with two channels). The strange part is that I can only see one device output. Moreover the `QCameraInfo` is also detecting just one device. Also out of two ports only one port provides the detection in `QCameraInfo` class.

Can anyone suggest me the possible reason. Or is there a way to select different channel using the Qt Class?

Comment: FInally it worked by using the sdk from theimaging group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to https://www.theimagingsource.de/produkte/grabber/pci-express/

Download the drivers and proper c++ library.